# How to handle create profile and edit profile using same form component in flux?

Tags: reactjs, flux

- Most of the form examples are create format (ex: Add Todo, Create user form, add comment form), not create & edit format (ex:Add/Modify todo, Create/Modify User form, Create/Modify comment form).
- I am trying to create/edit using same component. I don't know how to handle form fields.Should I create Form fields are controlled component/uncontrolled component?
- If Controlled Component, how to create store for form fields? where to handle client validation (ex: email id format ) & server validation (ex: email id already register)?
- If UnControlled Component, how to inject data into form fields? how to handle validations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

This question is very open-ended so I fear you will not receive satisfactory answers.

What you can do is:

- Search for examples on the internets. Googling for "React CRUD examples" gave me this: http://react.rocks/tag/CRUD and this: https://github.com/edshadi/flux-crud-example
- Pick one strategy and go with it. When you start facing problems with your architectural decisions, you can ask more specific questions here.

Good luck!